# LDAP search query to get one specific entry

Tags: ldap

I have before me [RFC 4515](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515.txt) that provides the String representation of **LDAP** search filters. I have also looked into the APIs of the [UnboundId SDK for Java](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) but it is not clear to me what is the best idiom to use when I expect my query to fetch **one, at most** LDAP entry. I have thought about using the **DN** of that entry as the *base* in the **LDAP** query but then, filtering makes really no sense and I have to use a contrived nonsense filter that will, be design, evaluate to true for the entry already indicated in the search **base**. I.e. there seems to be no *alwaysTrue* filter to use in the protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the distinguished name is known, use the distinguished name as the base object, use `SearchScope.BASE`, use a filter of `(&)` (or `objectClass=*`) and provide a list of the attributes the client requires. For example:

```
// exception handling not shown
final LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(host,port);
// some broken servers do not understand the legal filter '(&)', if
// your directory is broken in this way, use 'objectClass=*' and
// an equality filter can be created like:
// Filter filter = Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass","*");
final SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest(dn,SearchScope.Sub,"(&)",SearchRequest.ALL_USER_ATTRIBUTES);
final SearchResult result = conn.search(req);
final List<SearchResultEntry> entries = result.getSearchEntries();
conn.close();
```

This will return all user attributes for the entry. The same thing can be accomplished by:

```
// exception handling not shown
final LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(host,port);
final SearchResultEntry entry = conn.getEntry(dn);
conn.close();
```

If the distinguished name is known, the second method is most succinct. There is also a `getEntry(String dn,String attributes ...)` method should the client wish to specify a list of attributes to return. If the DN is not known, the client must search for the entry and the distinguished name is returned in the `SearchResultEntry` with every search request that returns at least one entry.

As for fetching at most one entry when multiple entries match a filter, the LDAP client must provide a sufficiently tight search scope and filter to narrow the result to the one entry that is required. That is what the filter and scope are for.